# Magento 2 : Product list only shows one product in one of the category, the rest works fine

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, category-products, reindex

Product list only shows one product in one of the category, the rest works fine. That category has more products, if you search for a product, you can access its product view and in related products the rest of products are showed.

Comment: what about 'Salable Quantity', Visibuility' and 'Status' in products list in dashboard? Are they ok?

Comment: and indexer? did you check it?

Comment: Yes, first thing I tried, and no changes

Comment: Go to the target category setting and check out "Products in Category". How many item in there?

Comment: 93 records found, that number is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90436/discussion-between-angel-carlos-del-pozo-muela-and-kirill-korushkin).